# Etcd member has no leader

Tags: containers, kubernetes, etcd, flannel, flanneld

I am new to Kubernetes and currently setting up Kubernetes cluster with 1 master and 2 minions on CentOS 7. I am following Kubernetes' official setup guide located [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/).

I configured etcd as per the documentation and after I run

> etcdctl mkdir /kube-centos/network

I get the following error

> Error:  client: etcd member http://0.0.0.0:2379 has no leader

Can anyone help me with this? I spent my whole day in it but I have no clue yet.

---

Providing below is the etcd.conf and flanneld config file for reference:

** etcd.conf **

```html
#[member]

ETCD_NAME=default
ETCD_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/etcd/default.etcd"
#ETCD_WAL_DIR=""
#ETCD_SNAPSHOT_COUNT="10000"
#ETCD_HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL="100"
#ETCD_ELECTION_TIMEOUT="1000"
#ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="http://localhost:2380"
ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:2379"
ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="http://localhost:2379"
#ETCD_MAX_SNAPSHOTS="5"
#ETCD_MAX_WALS="5"
#ETCD_CORS=""
#
#[cluster]
#ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS="http://localhost:2380"
# if you use different ETCD_NAME (e.g. test), set ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER value for this name, i.e. "test=http://..."
#ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER="default=http://localhost:2380"
#ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE="new"
#ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN="etcd-cluster"
ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:2379"
#ETCD_DISCOVERY=""
#ETCD_DISCOVERY_SRV=""
#ETCD_DISCOVERY_FALLBACK="proxy"
#ETCD_DISCOVERY_PROXY=""
#ETCD_STRICT_RECONFIG_CHECK="false"
#ETCD_AUTO_COMPACTION_RETENTION="0"
#
#[proxy]
#ETCD_PROXY="off"
#ETCD_PROXY_FAILURE_WAIT="5000"
#ETCD_PROXY_REFRESH_INTERVAL="30000"
#ETCD_PROXY_DIAL_TIMEOUT="1000"
#ETCD_PROXY_WRITE_TIMEOUT="5000"
#ETCD_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT="0"
#
#[security]
#ETCD_CERT_FILE=""
#ETCD_KEY_FILE=""
#ETCD_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH="false"
#ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=""
#ETCD_AUTO_TLS="false"
#ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=""
#ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=""
#ETCD_PEER_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH="false"
#ETCD_PEER_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=""
#ETCD_PEER_AUTO_TLS="false"
```

And below is the flannel configuration on the minions

```html
# Flanneld configuration options

# etcd url location.  Point this to the server where etcd runs
FLANNEL_ETCD_ENDPOINTS="http://node1:2379"

# etcd config key.  This is the configuration key that flannel queries
# For address range assignment
FLANNEL_ETCD_PREFIX="/atomic.io/network"

# Any additional options that you want to pass
#FLANNEL_OPTIONS=""
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of the guide states:

> ### Warning
>
> This guide has been deprecated. It was originally written for
>   Kubernetes 1.1.0. Please check [the latest guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/).

I strongly suggest you give that a go. That one actually works with CentOS 7. No sweat.

Comment: Hey Janos, thank you very much for your reply. I know I am replying late, but I was able to set up the cluster using new guide.